# Share gitlab CI/CD variables between projects

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a project that implements a shared CI library and other projects include it in their .gitlab-ci.yml files.
Also, all these projects share the same service account that is added as CI/CD variables to each project that wants to include the library.

I tried to set this service account as a CI/CD variable in the library project, but I can not share it with the projects consuming this library.

All these projects are in different groups and, at least until now, there is no need to move them.
Is there another way to share service accounts/ API keys among different projects consuming a CI library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your own runners, then [possibly](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16339#note_214902235).

If not, you might be able to write some tooling to retrieve the variables [via the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html).

Comment: I think the only issue with retrieving the variables using the API is that I'll need to add the access token to it on every project. Unfortunately, most of the projects are not in the same group

Comment: True, but you can add CI variables in the groups, and you probably have fewer groups than projects!